# check to see if every element inside an array is empty

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if the element is undefined and if its defined, all the elements inside it are empty, be it an array or nested arry or nested object

Here is the screenshot

**https://prnt.sc/n412fbl0aUvv**

My try till now

```
let validation=true;

for(let i=0;i<items.lenght;++i){
  if(Object.keys(items[i]).length===0) {
    validation =false;
    break;
  }
}
```

its not checking for everything here

Comment: ```const invalid = items.find((item) => !item || Object.values(item).find(val => !val));``` is one way to do it. This is a low quality question, please read **all** of [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking additional questions. Do not post code in images, and try to make a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

There is at least an array of objects nested in the `items` object.
And you wish to validate the nested objects too.

So you need a [recursive function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion) to test the nested items. You also need to know when the recursion hits an `array` or an `object`.

Have a look at `getType()`, a function to get the type of an item. It's needed because `typeof()` returns `object` for both an object or an array. Based on the returned type, `validation()` (the recursive function) can send the right `item` to the next recursion until the `item` is not an array or object. It can then check if it is an empty string. It also could be a `boolean`, a `number` or a `function` but in those cases, they will not contain a string to be tested.

```js
// Your item structure, as seen on the image in question
const items = {
  paymentItem: [
    {
      billingAccountNum: "",
      invoiceNumber: ""
    }
  ],
  transactionDate: "",
  transactionId: ""
};

// Function to get an item type
const getType = (item) => {
  let itemType = typeof(item)
  if(itemType === "object"){
    itemType = Array.isArray(item) ? "array" : "object"
  }
  
  return itemType
}

// The recursive function to turn isValid to false if there is one empty string.
const validation = (item) => {
  if(getType(item) === "object"){
    Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => validation(item[key]))  // Recursion here.
    return
  }
  if(getType(item) === "array"){
    item.forEach((element) => validation(element))  // Recursion here.
    return
  }
  
  if(item === ""){
    isValid = false
  }
}

// Validation variable
let isValid = true

// Validation function call
validation(items)

// Final result
console.log("first test:", isValid)

// ==============
// Let's do a second test where only one property is empty
const items2 = {
  paymentItem: [
    {
      billingAccountNum: "",
      invoiceNumber: 84566
    }
  ],
  transactionDate: "2023-01-15T00:20:00",
  transactionId: "HS9873-1"
};

// Reset the validation variable
isValid = true

// Validation function call
validation(items2)

// Final result
console.log("second test:", isValid)
```

Comment: so both are coming as false, why?

Comment: Second test was to show it catches an empty string in nested object. I did not made an example where it will output a `true` because it's too obvious. You can try it right?